# Why does python script in current directory need ./ for execution with shebang?

Tags: python, shebang

In my current directory there is the executable script.py with the shebang `#!/usr/bin/env python`. To execute it in bash, I need to type `./script.py`. From what I read about shebang I would expect `script.py` to execute the script too, same as `python script.py` does, but it doesn't. What is the difference between the two latter options?

Comment: This is a security feature of the shell. Image `root` goes to a user's home folder and the user placed a nasty script called `ls` there.

Comment: Without the "in this directory" indicator `./` your shell will search your `PATH` for `script.py`. Your current directory probably isn't on the path, whereas `python`'s directory is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Un*x-like systems, `.` is not in the path for security reasons, in order to avoid executing a command like `ls` which could be in a user directory (this security breach is best exploited as root)

This is less concerning for python scripts than for classic commands like `ls`, but python scripts with a shebang are executables so the obey the general security rules.

When you type `python myscript.py` you *know* that the script is in the current directory, and `python` reads it from here, regardless of the system path (it's seen as *data*, not as *executable*, the real executable being `python`)